# I need to send SQL command using python to INNER JOIN two TABLES

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

This is my python code:

```
qry1 = """UPDATE mydb.table1"""
qry2 = """INNER JOIN mydb.table2 ON mydb.table1.item1 = mydb.table2.item1"""
qry3 = """SET mydb.table1.item1 = If(mydb.table2.item1 > 0, mydb.table2.item1, mydb.table1.item1)"""

cursor.execute(qry1)
cursor.execute(qry2)
cursor.execute(qry3)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

How to execute this correctly?

Comment: Look at the [multi-table syntax for update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). Hint - its one query, not 3.

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem. I'm new here. How can I add a check to your comment.

Comment: you're welcome. welcome to SO. I wasn't going to write a full answer for it. You seemed close enough to work it out yourself. Feel free to write your answer however.